# How to get the checkbox values on windows load event using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I have a view as follows

```
@if(Model.Is_Prefix_Checked == 1)
                {
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-md-1" style='align-content:center;'>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="Is_Prefix_Checked" name="IsPrefixChecked" checked="checked" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Prefix</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select asp-for="EmployeePrefix" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.prefix"  >
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="EmployeePrefix" class="text-danger" ></span>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div>
                        <div class="col-md-1" style='align-content:center;'>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="largerCheckbox" id="Is_Prefix_Checked" name="IsPrefixChecked">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Prefix</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <select asp-for="EmployeePrefix" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.prefix">
                        </select>
                        <span asp-validation-for="EmployeePrefix" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>

                }
```

when i click on the checkbox i am getting the value ,  but when i come back to the page the checkbox is already clicked and now when i try to update the form the already clicked checkbox value are showing as 0 instead of 1 .

I need to do this for more than for 20 fields in each page

My jquery is as follows

```
<script>
        window.onload = function () {
            
            func2();
        }
</script>

<script>
        function func2() {
            window.onload=function()
            {
                 const checkBoxes=document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");
                 const checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll
                for(var i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (this.checked) 
                    {
                        $(this).attr("value", "1");
                    } else
                    {
                        $(this).attr("value", "0");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        // this is the scrpt for checkbox
        $(document).on("click", "[type='checkbox']", function (e) {
            if (this.checked) {
                $(this).attr("value", "1");
            } else {
                $(this).attr("value", "0");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean about update the form in "when i try to update the form the already clicked checkbox value are showing as 0 instead of 1 ."?  How you update? And after you update what the checkbox value you want to see? Besides, how you display more than for 20 fields ?

Comment: Its like a validation checkbox where the manager will validate every text filed with checkbox . When the checkbox is clicked the textbox will become readonly and the user will not be able to change anything . The reason for update is if there is any incorrect filed and if the user is correcting and submitting the form again the manager has to again validate it . so when the manager loads the page the already checked checkbox are appearing as marked checked but when now when i update the page the checked checkbox values are 0 instead of 1. i need get it as 1 if is already checked.

Comment: When you  update  the form then load the page, your  jquery result won't keep, so 'when i update the page the checked checkbox values are 0 instead of 1". I suggest you try to use ajax to submit the form, then the  jquery result will keep .

Comment: i found a way . Just by adding value tag in if else condition we can achive it.